# Navigate to url inside errorhandler

Tags: angular

I tired to implement a global ErrorHandler below:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    handleError(error:any): void {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
            const injector = Injector.create({providers: [{provide: Router, deps :[]}]});
            injector.get(Router).navigateByUrl('/login');
        }
    }
}
```

When I received a 401 response, i got a TypeError: StaticInjectorError[RouterModule -> Router]: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you create your own `injector`?

Add the `injector` as constructor param and use that:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    constructor(private readonly injector: Injector) {}

    handleError(error:any): void {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
            this.injector.get(Router).navigateByUrl('/login');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there is a reason behind trying to inject router the way you did. 
But you could do it like this if its suits you.
Add the router to the constructor and use it to navigate when you get 401

```
    @Injectable()
    export class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    constructor(private _router:Router){}
        handleError(error:any): void {
            if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
                this._router.navigate(['/login']);
            }
        }
```